# HTML range input, larger values take up less space in the range input

Tags: html

It is hard to explain this with words.  I drew a crude picture to show what I mean:

[image]

Let's say we have an `input=range` element with `min=0`, `max=100`, `step=1`.

By default, the steps are distributed evenly.  So a range value of 50 would be in the middle of the element.

I want a range value of 25 to be in the middle of the element.  This means the first 25 steps to take up 50% of the range, and the remaining 75 steps to take up the remaining 50% of the range.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you want a sort of logarithmic scale.  There's nothing built-in for this, but it's not a problem to take your value and calculate the effective value in JavaScript based on whatever the raw value is.

Comment: @Brad Yes logarithmic is the right word for this.  I'm not sure if you meant by your 2nd sentence.  How can I apply that to achieve the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Set `min` to `0`, set `max` to `1`, set `step` to `0.01` or whatever you'd like.  Then multiply by some factor on `change`.

Answer (score 0):

Range inputs are always linear, and there are no other curve options built-in.  You will have to calculate that curve yourself.

Let's start by modifying your input range to be from `0` to `1`.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" />
```

An easy way to get the sort of curve you're asking for is with a sine function.  By multiplying the value by `PI/2`, we end up with the desirable curve:

[image: Sine Curve from 0 to 1]

(You can [fiddle with it on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20%3D%20sin(x*pi%2F2)%20from%200%20to%201).)

This is easy enough to implement in JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  console.log(Math.sin(e.target.value * Math.PI/2));
});
```

I've put a full example up on JSFiddle, with an SVG visualization:  https://jsfiddle.net/rexLoczj/1/